# how to share data to all view in laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravel-5.7

I have a login form. I want when user login success, my controller will select data of this user and share to all view.

I read laravel docs. [This][1] advises me to use the *"View::share('key', 'value');"*
in boot method of AppServiceProvider, but i dont know how to call it in my controller

my controller:

```
if( Auth::attempt(['mssv' => $username,'password' =>$password])) {
                $user=SinhVien::where('mssv',$username)->first();

       //i want to share $user to all view in here

                $success = new MessageBag(['successlogin' => 'Login Success]);
                return redirect()->back()->withErrors($success);
            }
else {
            $errors = new MessageBag(['errorlogin' => 'Login Fail']);
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors($errors);
        }
```

and in all view blade, I use:

```
{{$user->name}}
```

Please help!
[1]: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/views#sharing-data-with-all-views

Comment: just use it in your parent layout or header.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade#template-inheritance

Comment: use it as
 `@if(auth()->user) {{ auth()->user->name }} @else <button>login</button> @endif`

Comment: i read it @OmarAbdullah, Like I mentioned in the question. but i dont know how to call it in my controller

Comment: First answer this. Why do you need to share it to all views ? So we get on the same page

Comment: because i want to show it in all view. how to use it when i share data, which is not auth

Comment: OK. So you want to share logged in $user to all the views. Am i right

Comment: yep, that right

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183771/discussion-between-omar-abdullah-and-the-manh-nguyen).

Answer (score 0):

In your blades you would then have access to the `key` from the `View::share('key', 'value');` you put in the `AppServiceProvider`.

So if the key is `user`, in your blades you just use the `$user` variable.

Comment: how to put it to AppServiceProvider from my controller

Comment: You don't put it from the controller.  The most example of needing to do this is for the current logged in User, but it could be anything.  In your `AppServiceProvider`, you do a query to get out any data from the DB you need, then do the `View::share`.  So if you update the user in a controller (the name for example), your `AppServiceProvider` should automatically pick that up.

Comment: in my question, i was select data of user in controller, and i want share it to all view

Answer (score -1):

```
<!-- Stored in resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php -->

<html>
<head>
    <title>App Name - @yield('title')</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
     <div>
      @if(auth()->user()) 
          {{ auth()->user()->name }} 
       @else 
           <button>login</button> 
      @endif
      <div>
   </header>

    <div class="container">
        @yield('content')
    </div>
</body>
```

**EDIT :**

`{{ auth()->user->name }}` corrected ->  `{{ auth()->user()->name }}`

Comment: `user` in auth() is a method, not an attribute. you are missing the `()`.